# Может ли DataAdapter получить значение из определенного столбца

Tags: c#, база-данных

Насколько знаю `DataReader` считывает из БД таблицы построчно а `DataAdapter` целиком. Но при этом если нужно обратиться к какому то столбцу, то с помощью `DataReader` это можно сделать так:

```
DataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.GetString(1) != "empty")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Где **`1`** это номер столбца от нуля. Вопрос: есть ли аналогичный инструмент у `DataAdapter`? На msdn ничего похожего не нашел, но может что-то не так понял или пропустил.

Comment: `DataAdapter` заполняет `DataTable`. Вот в заполненном `DataTable` и берём нужный столбец. Если другие столбцы вообще не нужны, то делаем конкретный sql-запрос: `SELECT column_name FROM ...`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `DataReader` тоже заполняет таблицу - метод `Load()`. только столбец может содержать значение >0 или <0. и если больше то таблица будет заполнена, если меньше то нет.

Comment: Ага, я понял, что нужно. Ну, тогда только вручную выполнять фильтрацию, именно как показано в вопросе. Или, опять же, модифицировать sql-запрос: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`. Этот подход самый правильный.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавить `where`  я тоже пробовал.  загвоздка в том, что мне нужно сравнить с нулем не столбец таблицы, а результат  сложения двух ячеек разных столбцов. т.е. у меня не получиться **where `colunmName` >0** потому что `colunmName` выглядит примерно так - **(sum(col1))-(sum(col2))**